# Which save file actually holds the information on the blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My cousin and I  were building on a server, and yes it was modded. It corrupted and now I have been able to get the player information into a new save, but the world file itself I also need, and I can't figure out which file that is.

Folders within the save folder:

- data
- DIM1
- DIM-1
- DIM-37
- DIM-38
- DIM-39
- DIM-42
- DIM-100
- DIM-112
- livSandStoneData
- playerdata [Which is the one I used to get the player info]
- region
- stats

Files within the Saves folder:

- forcedchunks.dat
- labyrinth.dat
- labyrinth.dat_old
- level.dat
- level.cat_mcr
- level.dat_old
- session.lockl
- teams_Mirror.cat
- teams_Nether.dat
- teams_Overworld.dat
- teams_Spirit World.dat
- teams_The End.dat
- teams_The Last Millenium.dat
- teams_The Outer Lands.dat
- teams_Torment.dat
- teams_Underdark.dat

Comment: Every corruption of those data can be fixed, but it depends on what happened. If you can get crash logs and read them properly, then you can find the source of corruption and fix it, there is plenty of tools for that. But that would be another question, and probably not to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

**All of those are your world's save data.** There's no single file that contains all the block data — it's spread out amongst multiple files within each dimension folder. Leaving any of those out will lose some parts of your world.

(The only exception is the session lock file: it's only used to make sure Minecraft and some other program (like MCEdit) don't both try to change the world at the same time, so it doesn't contain any actual data and you should delete that if you're setting up a new server using this world save.)

It's possible to selectively leave out some parts, such as “resetting” your Nether by leaving out the `DIM-1` folder, or removing specific chunk files inside a dimension folder to reset that chunk. But if you want *everything*, you just copy over the whole folder.

If the world is corrupted somewhere and you need to leave that part behind, you will have to figure out where in the world that corruption is, then what files contain that part of the world, and then leave that set of files behind in the transfer. Note that many of those `.dat` files contain the information necessary for mods to remember the non-block parts they add to the world, and figuring out what they contain will require consulting mod documentation or the mod author.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem on my modded MC Server. The problem occurred because I started up the server twice and made /fml confirm (because level.dat was already in use). So the world was corrupted.

I fixed it by removing level.dat and then copied level.dat_old and renamed to level.dat. So I have reset to the time before I did /fml confirm. Maybe this will help you too. (You also have this level.dat_old file.)

Answer (score -1):

I have had something similar to that and yes it did corrupt from what it sounds like. Theres no way to fix it you just have to rebuild it

Comment: There is one way but I don't think you would have backed up you computer when the server was still working